# What does :except => {:no_release => true} mean in Capistrano DSL

Tags: capistrano, dsl

For example in:

```
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
 end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looking at the [handbook](https://github.com/leehambley/capistrano-handbook/blob/master/index.markdown), it appears that you can pass the `:no_release` attribute to the `role` definition (commonly done for the web role). This indicates that the code should not be checked out on servers in that role.

So, I'm guessing that when a task specifies `:except => { :no_release => true }` - it's saying "Skip this task on the servers (roles) that have `:no_release` defined as `true`."

```
role :app, "your app-server here"
role :web, "your web-server here", :no_release => true
role :db,  "your db-server here", :primary => true
```

...

```
desc "restart passenger"
task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
end
```

In the above example, the restart operation should not run on the web server. Again, this is not tested... just going by my observations.